# How to understand the Matlab build in function "kmeans"?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-analysis

Suppose I have a matrix `A`, the size of which is `2000*1000 double`. Then I apply 
Matlab build in function `"kmeans"`to the matrix `A`.

```
k = 8;
[idx,C] = kmeans(A, k, 'Distance', 'cosine');
```

I get `C = 8*1000 double`; `idx = 2000*1 double`, with values from 1 to 8;
According to the documentation, `C` returns the k cluster centroid locations in the `k-by-p (8 by 1000)` matrix. And `idx` returns an `n-by-1 vector` containing cluster indices of each observation. 
My question is:

1) I do not know how to understand the `C`, the centroid locations. Locations should be represented as `(x,y)`, right? How to understand the matrix `C` correctly?

2) What are the final centers `c1, c2,...,ck`? Are they just values or locations?

3) For each cluster, if I only want to get the vector closest to the center of this cluster, how to calculate and get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer the three parts, I'll just explain the syntax that is used in MATLAB's explanation of k-means (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html).

- `A` is your data matrix (it's represented as `X` in the link). There are `n` rows (in this case, 2000), which represent the number of observations/data points that you have. There are also `p` columns (in this case, 1000), which represent the number of "features" that each data points has. For example, if your data consisted of 2D points, then `p` would equal 2.
- `k` is the number of clusters that you want to group the data into. Based on the dimensions of `C` that you gave, `k` must be 8.

Now I will answer the three parts:

1. The `C` matrix has dimensions `k x p`. Each row represents a centroid. Centroid locations DO NOT have to be (x, y) at all. The dimensions of the centroid locations are equal to `p`. In other words, if you have 2D points, you could graph the centroids as (x, y). If you have 3D points, you could graph the centroids as (x, y, z). Since each data point in `A` has 1000 features, your centroids therefore have 1000 dimensions.
2. This is sort of difficult to explain without knowing what your data is exactly. Centroids are certainly not just values, and they may not necessarily be locations. If your data `A` were coordinate points, you could certainly represent the centroids as locations. However, we can view it more generally. If you had a cluster centroid `i` and the data points `v` that are grouped with that centroid, the centroid would represent the data point that is most similar to those in its cluster. Hopefully, that makes sense, and I can give a clearer explanation if necessary.
3. The k-means method actually gives us a good way to accomplish this. The function actually has 4 possible outputs, but I will focus on the 4th, which I will call `D`:

   ```
   [idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(A, k, 'Distance', 'cosine');
   ```

   `D` has dimensions `n x k`. For a data point `i`, the row `i` in the `D` matrix gives the distance from that point to every centroid. Therefore, for each centroid, you simply need to find the data point closest to this, and return that corresponding data point. I can supply the short code for this if you need it.

Also, just a tip. You should probably use kmeans++ method of initializing the centroids. It's faster and generally better. You can call it using this:

```
[idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(A, k, 'Distance', 'cosine', 'Start', 'plus');
```

### Edit:

Here is the code necessary for part 3:

```
[~, min_idxs] = min(D, [], 1);
closest_vecs = A(min_idxs, :);
```

Each row `i` of `closest_vecs` is the vector that is closest to centroid `i`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Impressive for just being a high school student. Btw welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Also, pop by our MATLAB chatroom to say hi whenever you have time :). http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you :D. I'm actually at a research camp right now working with k-means and spatial pyramid pooling, so this isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: K means is one of the first machine learning algorithms I learned. Very simple indeed. The algorithms to compute closest pairs though... To get it efficient is actually a bit difficult. Brute force flat out sucks. Hope you have fun! I've also upvoted your post.

Comment: @It'sMagic, you said "Therefore, for each centroid, you simply need to find the data point closest to this, and return that corresponding data point. I can supply the short code for this if you need it." Yes, I need it, Please supply the short code for this.

Comment: @Shawn I edited my response to add this code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @It'sMagic, the size of "closest_vecs" is 8*1000 double. It seems the number of features is still the same (in this case, 1000). kmeans just reduce the observations/data points. Compared to spatial pyramid pooling, what is the advantage here?

Comment: @It'sMagic, if using spatial pyramid pooling, what is the result?

Comment: @Shawn K-means doesn't actually reduce the number of observations or data points, but makes it easier to group data points. Spatial pyramid pooling actually relies on a variant of k-means, called bag of features (BoF). I read about it through this paper: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/Fall2014/CS9840/Papers/lazebnikcvpr06b.pdf. It only really works with images. However, if you would like a simpler explanation of it, just let me know.

Comment: @It'sMagic, yes, I would like a simpler explanation. Why spatial pyramid pooling only works for images. The images you mean grey scale image and RGB images?

Comment: @It'sMagic, can spatial pyramid pooling be used here？

Comment: Spatial pyramid pooling only really makes sense when your data is images. It basically forms a histogram of features for the image, splits it into smaller regions, and computes histograms for those regions. Trying to split any other data into these "regions' is pretty hard and impractical. I've only ever implemented it with greyscale. I assume it could be possible to implement with RGB images, though it would just make things needlessly complicated. I gtg for half an hour, but if you still have any questions, you can just post a question, as I need a bit of room to explain it.

Comment: @It'sMagic， If I have a matrix B, the size of which is 500*1000 double (500 represents time points, 1000 represents different features). And assume I also have a label vector L, the size of which is 500*1 (values go from 1 to 5). The label vector L exactly corresponds to the 500 time points. Does spatial pyramid pooling works for this situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85262/discussion-between-its-magic-and-shawn).

Answer (score 0):

OK, before we actually get into the details, let's give a brief overview on what *K*-means clustering is first.

---

[*k*-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) works such that for some data that you have, you want to group them into *k* groups.  You initially choose *k* random points in your data, and these will have labels from `1,2,...,k`.  These are what we call the **centroids**. Then, you determine how close the rest of the data are to each of these points.  You then group those points so that whichever points are closest to any of these *k* points, you assign those points to belong to that particular group (`1,2,...,k`).  After, for all of the points for each group, you update the **centroids**, which actually is defined as the representative point for each group.  For each group, you compute the average of all of the points in each of the *k* groups.  These become the **new** centroids for the next iteration.  In the next iteration,  you determine how close each point in your data is to **each of the centroids**.  You keep iterating and repeating this behaviour until the centroids don't move anymore, or they move very little.

---

How you use the `kmeans` function in MATLAB is that assuming you have a data matrix (`A` in your case), it is arranged such that each row is a sample and each column is a feature / dimension of a sample.  For example, we could have `N x 2` or `N x 3` arrays of Cartesian coordinates, either in 2D or 3D.  In colour images, we could have `N x 3` arrays where each column is a colour component in an image - red, green or blue.

How you invoke `kmeans` in MATLAB is the following way:

```
[IDX, C] = kmeans(X, K);
```

`X` is the data matrix we talked about, `K` is the total number of clusters / groups you would like to see and the outputs `IDX` and `C` are respectively an **index** and **centroid** matrix.  `IDX` is a `N x 1` array where `N` is the total number of samples that you have put into the function.  Each value in `IDX` tells you **which centroid** the sample / row in `X` best matched with a particular centroid.  You can also override the distance measure used to measure the distance between points. By default, this is the Euclidean distance, but you used the cosine distance in your invocation.

`C` has `K` rows where each row is a centroid.  Therefore, for the case of Cartesian coordinates, this would be a `K x 2` or `K x 3` array.  Therefore, you would interpret `IDX` as telling which group / centroid that the point is closest to when computing *k*-means.  As such, if we got a value of `IDX=1` for a point, this means that the point best matched with the first centroid, which is the first row of `C`.  Similarly,  if we got a value of `IDX=1` for a point, this means that the point best matched with the third centroid, which is the third row of `C`.

---

Now to answer your questions:

1. We just talked about `C` and `IDX` so this should be clear.
2. The final centres are stored in `C`.  Each row gives you a centroid / centre that is representative of a group.
3. It sounds like you want to find the closest point to each cluster in the data, besides the actual centroid itself.  That's easy to do if you use [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) which performs K-Nearest Neighbour search by giving a set of points and it outputs the `K` closest points within your data that are close to a query point.  As such, you supply the clusters as the input and your data as the output, then use `K=2` and skip the first point.  The first point will have a distance of 0 as this will be equal to the centroid itself and the second point will give you the closest point that is closest to the cluster.

   You can do that by the following, assuming you already ran `kmeans`:

   ```
   out = knnsearch(A, C, 'k', 2);
   out = out(:,2);
   ```

   You run `knnsearch`, then toss out the closest point as it would essentially have a distance of 0.  The second column is what you're after, which gives you the closest point to the cluster excluding the actual centroid.  `out` will give you which points in your data matrix `A` that was closest to each centroid.  To get the actual points, do this:

   ```
   pts = A(out,:);
   ```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, for part 3, for each cluster, I believe he wants the data point that is closest to each cluster. It should be extremely easy to do, considering the k-means function also gives the distance from each point to every centroid.

Comment: @It'sMagic - Makes sense.  I'll edit my post, but I'll also wait for confirmation too.

Comment: @It'sMagic - BTW, you can just use `knnsearch` and specify `k=2` and throw out the first point.

Comment: @It'sMagic yes, you are right. For each cluster, only the vector closest to the center of cluster is retained. That is what I want.